# Paramter pack unfolding correctly to initialize a std::array of std::strings

Tags: c++, c++17

currently i am playing around with parameter packs in c++. I have wrote this little snippet:

```
template<typename ...Targs>
auto toString(Targs... args) -> std::array<std::string,sizeof...(Targs)> 
{
    return {
              {
                 (std::forward<std::string>(std::to_string(args)),...)
              }
           };
}
```

It has no real purpose but the exercise was/is to create an array of strings from the given parameter which can vary in count and type.

What I hoped to achieve was to do the following:

```
std::array<std::string,3> SomeName = { {std::to_string(1),std::to_string(2),std::to_string(3)} };
```

but more generic. That was the idea for the `toString` function. Unfortunately the result I get is not what I expected. The returned `std::array` will only contain the last parameter given to `toString` with the rest of the strings being empty.

But what I actually expected was that each argument given to `toString` gets converted into an string and put into the element of the array.

What did I miss about parameter pack unfolding? Or do I have just annoyingly stupid mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra comma:

```
(std::forward<std::string>(std::to_string(args)),...)
//                                              ^
```

This now becomes a fold expression over a comma, which is a single expression that gives you one string, where you want `N` strings. Also, the term isn't unfolding, the term is parameter pack *expansion*.

Removing the comma gives you what you want:

```
return {{std::to_string(args)...}};
```

Note that the `std::forward<>` is unnecessary - so I removed that too.